# ошибка при использовании typedef

Tags: c++, c, typedef

В данном коде компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
>    typedef int[CUBE_DIMENSION][CUBE_DIMENSION] Side;
>
> error: ‘Side’ does not name a type
>    typedef Side[NUM_SIDES] Cube;
>
> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
>    typedef int[CUBE_DIMENSION] Row, Column;

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, что означает *unqualified-id* 
или чем вызвана данная ошибка?

```
...  
#define CUBE_DIMENSION 3
#define NUM_SIDES 6   

typedef int[CUBE_DIMENSION][CUBE_DIMENSION] Side;
typedef Side[NUM_SIDES] Cube;
typedef int[CUBE_DIMENSION] Row, Column;
...
```

Comment: сделай тип `int[CUBE_DIMENSION] SideInner` потом `typedef SideInner[CUBE_DIMENSION] Side`

Comment: @eri, error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
 typedef int[CUBE_DIMENSION] SideInner;

Comment: Я с телефона писал.. Похоже промахнулся

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array люди подсказывают, что массивы нужно определять наизнанку

```
typedef int Side[CUBE_DIMENSION][CUBE_DIMENSION];
```

Answer (score 5):

`typedef`, грубо говоря, работает как объявление переменной - только вместо переменной - тип.

Например, как выглядит объявление двумерного массива 10x10?

```
int array[10][10];
```

Значит, для определения *типа* двумерного массива 10x10 надо дописать `typedef`:

```
typedef int array[10][10];
```

Другое дело в C++ `using` - тут и в самом деле немного не так:

```
using array = int[10][10];
```